# why still return false?

Tags: php, date

Does anyone know why this function still returns false?

function page:

```
function validateDate($date)
{
  $array = array();
  $array = explode("-", $date);
  if (strlen($array[1]) != 1 || strlen($array[1]) != 2) {
    return false;
  } else if (strlen($array[0] != 1 || strlen($array[0] != 2))) {
    return false;
  } else if (strlen($array[2] != 4)) {
    return false;
  } else if (checkdate($array[1], $array[0], $array[2]) == false) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

validate page:

```
if (validateDate($_POST['birth']) == false) {
    ?><img class="inputCheckImg" src="<?= ICON ?>cross.png"><a class="inputCheckCross">This is not a valid date.</a><?
}
```

And the input is: `8-5-1996` or `08-05-1996`.
I tried both, but both doesn't work.

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` well this won't help you much to find an error

Comment: oops didn't removed that. i will look do you have a minute?

Comment: I changed it in my code to `E_ALL` but still no errors :(

Comment: If it didn't I wouldn't ask it here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your very first test:

```
 if (strlen($array[1]) != 1 || strlen($array[1]) != 2) {
    return false;
```

Every string has a length that is not equal to 1, or not equal to 2. That is, a string of length 1 will fail the second part of the test and a string of length 2 will fail the first part. Change the operator to `&&`.

```
 if (strlen($array[1]) != 1 && strlen($array[1]) != 2) {
    return false;
```

Check your other tests for similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

I got it Thx to Hobo Sapiens and TheChafing.

But 1 more thing I changed.

instead of `!=` I used `<` or `>`

So what it is now:

```
function validateDate($date)
{
$array = array();
$array = explode("-", $date);
if (strlen($array[1]) < 1 && strlen($array[1]) > 2) {
    return false;
  } else if (strlen($array[0] < 1 && strlen($array[0] > 2))) {
    return false;
  } else if (strlen($array[2] != 4)) {
    return false;
  } else if (checkdate($array[1], $array[0], $array[2]) == false) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: your other strlens are still wrong
else if (strlen($array[0] != 1 || strlen($array[0] != 2))) {
    return false;
it needs to be 
else if (   strlen($array[0]) != 1 && strlen($array[0]) != 2    ) {

Answer (score 0):

your strlen has a misplaced close bracket

strlen($array[2]) != 1

etc

Answer (score 0):

In your if statments like this:

```
if (strlen($array[1]) != 1 || strlen($array[1]) != 2) {
    return false;
}
```

You're checking if that element is != 1 OR !=2.  It's not going to be equal to both, so one of those will evaluate to true, causing the function to return false.

From what I can tell,  you probably want to be using the && operator there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PHP often, but I'm curious as to why Kris Zani as downvoted.

To me

```
      } else if (strlen($array[0] != 1 || strlen($array[0] != 2))) {
        return false;
      }
```

looks broken to hell and back. In my mind it should be:

```
   if (strlen($array[0]) != 1 || strlen($array[0]) != 2)
```